# Mixing linear and datetime x-axes with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to build a chart with Highcharts that contains 2 series: 1 spline and 1 line(step mode). For the spline, I want it on a linear x axis where each point is just evenly spaced out (by supplying only the Y value). The line I'd like on a datetime x axis.

My x-axes are defined as such:

```
xAxis: [{ // 0
  type: 'datetime',
  dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
    month: '%e. %b',
    year: '%b'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Date'
  }
}, { // 1
  type: 'linear',
  dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
    month: '%e. %b',
    year: '%b'
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tickLength: 0
}]
```

And my series as such:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Winter 2013-2014',
  data: [
    [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 29), 0],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.4],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 1), 0.25],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 1), 1.66],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 10), 1.8],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 19), 1.76],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 25), 2.62],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19), 2.41],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 30), 2.05],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 14), 1.7],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 24), 1.1],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 10), 0],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 13), 1.65],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 15), 1.29],
    [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 23), .88]
  ],
  type: 'line',
  step: true,
  xAxis: 0
}, {
  name: 'Winter 2014-2015',
  data: [
    2.63,
    2.77,
    2.68,
    2.56,
    2.39,
    2.3,
    2,
    1.85,
    1.49,
    1.08,
    2.4,
    1.8,
    1.9,
    1.9,
    2.3
  ],
  xAxis: 1,
  type: 'spline'
}]
```

Here is the full fiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish:

http://jsfiddle.net/bmxpert1/jgxjsfyd/4/

So the problem is then that the linear x-axis doesn't watch to stretch the full width of the chart. If I remove the step line on the datetime axis from the series array, the linear spline will draw full width but adding a series to the datetime axis seems to break the linear axis.

Hoping there's something obvious I'm missing. Appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ticks in your two x-axis are being aligned. This is enabled by default.

You can disable the alignment with this code:

```
chart: {
    alignTicks: false
}
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgxjsfyd/5/) demonstration. Also [see the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) for details.

Comment: Yep, something obvious I missed. Thanks!